# Share Service between 2 controllers and routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which I would like to convert into a service, this is the controller which is for list of orders app.

```
angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.detalleOrden = [{
            id: '12423',
            title: 'Detalles de la orden',
            supervisor: 'Someone',
            responsable: 'Someone Else',
            solicitante: 'Recope',
            unidadEjec: 'Grupo Planificador Belén'
            },
        {
            id: '56456',
            title: 'Detalles de la orden',
            supervisor: 'Carlos Blabla',
            responsable: 'Alberto Blablo',
            solicitante: 'Recope',
            unidadEjec: 'Grupo VEINSA'
            }];

  });
```

I want to do that because I have a view where users might see the the `title` property, once you click on that `title` you should be redirected to the view where you are able to see the full detail of the order.

then I need to create a controller to display the full info of the order, something like this

```
angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderIdCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope) {

        $log.info($routeParams.id);

  });
```

and then the config function

```
  .when('/orders', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'OrderDetailCtrl'
  })
  .when('/orders/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/order-detail.html',
    controller: 'OrderIdCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/orders'
  });
```

here is the HTML where you should see the `title` of the orders

```
    <div ng-repeat="detalle in detalleOrden">
      <a ng-href="#/orders/{{detalle.id}}">
        <h4 heading">Order {{detalle.id}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{detalle.unidadEjec}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
```

and here the view where might see the full order in detail

```
            <table ng-repeat="detalle in detalleOrden">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Supervisor</th>
                        <td>{{detalle.supervisor}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Responsable:</th>
                        <td>{{detalle.responsable}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Solicitante:</th>
                        <td>{{detalle.solicitante}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Unidad ejecutora:</th>
                        <td>{{detalle.unidadEjec}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

so I need to create a service with the info I place above, am I right ?

or what are your suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to switch to a service or factory.

I'm using promises here so that if you ever switch to `$http` your controller code won't have to change.

```
angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, Order) {

    Order.list().then(function(orders) {
      $scope.detalleOrden = orders;
    }, function() {
      $log('error');
    });

  });

angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderIdCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, Order) {

    $scope.order = {};

    Order.list().then(function(orders) {
      for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
        if(orders[i].id === $routeParams.id) { 
          $scope.order = orders[i];
        }
      }
    }, function() {
      $log('error');
    });

  });
```

You can inject this Factory directly into your controller and call its `list` method.

```
angular.module('recopeApp')
  .factory('Order', function ($q) {    
    return {
      list: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve([{
          id: '12423',
          title: 'Detalles de la orden',
          supervisor: 'Someone',
          responsable: 'Someone Else',
          solicitante: 'Recope',
          unidadEjec: 'Grupo Planificador Belén'
        }, {
          id: '56456',
          title: 'Detalles de la orden',
          supervisor: 'Carlos Blabla',
          responsable: 'Alberto Blablo',
          solicitante: 'Recope',
          unidadEjec: 'Grupo VEINSA'
        }]);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

Taking this a step further you could use resolve the orders in the router and inject the results into your controller. Here's what would change if you went with resolve:

```
  .when('/orders', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'OrderDetailCtrl',
    resolve: {
      orders: function(Order) {
        return Order.list();
      }
    }
  })

  .when('/orders/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/order-detail.html',
    controller: 'OrderIdCtrl',
    resolve: { 
      order: function(Order, $routeParams) {
        Order.list().then(function(orders) {
          for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            if(orders[i].id === $routeParams.id) { 
              return orders[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

Controller changes to this:

```
angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, orders) {    
    $scope.detalleOrden = orders;   
  });

angular.module('recopeApp')
  .controller('OrderIdCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, order) {    
    $scope.order = order;   
  });
```

Comment: I have that part already, the issue I have now is with the routing part. Once I try to go to ```/orders/:id```

Comment: I'll add how you'd change the router using the `resolve` method.

Comment: I added both controllers under both scenarios. The idea is that for one controller you want a list, for the other controller you want a single item.

Comment: I am getting an error once I try to redirect to the full post: ```Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: OrdersProvider <- Orders <- order```

Comment: Sorry, just fix it, was a typo.

Comment: I have a new issue. The view for ```OrderDetailCtrl``` is working properly by doing ```ng-repeat=list in detalleOrden```. But I can not see anything in the ```OrderIdCtrl```'s view, there I am not using any ```ng-repeat``` yet.